# What kind of List is List<Object> list = Database.getAllData();?

Tags: java, list

I have the following question:

if I have the following line of code:

```
List<Position> allPos = posDBM.getAllPos();
```

`Position` is an object

`posDBM` is a SQLite Database Manager class, which manages the SQLite database,
`getAllPos()` returns all database data.

The return type of `getAllPos()` is `List<Position>`.

If I want to initialize a `List<>` like this `List<Position> pos = new`, I have to specify the type of the `List` (ArrayList, LinkedList, etc.) .

So back to my question, what kind of List do I have, after I filled the list from the database?

I would guess it's an `ArrayList` , but I can't find any source to back this up. It's just a matter of interest...

Comment: Have you tried getClass().getName()??

Comment: You can just debug and see what the list implementation is. Or see the source returning the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It you are just curious, then one way to find out is to do something like this:

```
    List<Position> allPos = posDBM.getAllPos();
    System.out.println("The class is " + allPos.getClass().getName());
```

Of course, you don't *need* to know ... because you don't need to instantiate the list implementation class yourself.  The database management code deals with that.

Answer (score 8):

You don't have to know; that's the point.  The interface is what matters to you, not the implementation.

You can't know without looking at the source of that method.  But even if you do, it's immaterial to your client. All you call are `List` methods.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the quick answer. I was just wondering, that's all

Answer (score 2):

That you will find in getAllPos() source code. `List<Position>` due to Polymorphism will accept all classes implementing List interface.

Answer (score 1):

The returned `List<Position>` is a generic or a `Strongly Typed` list. The option that you were asking is about `ArrayList` which specifies a list that can take up any object. This will require an overhead of Boxing and Unboxing when writing / reading using the `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should not worried about the actual implementation , once you have List returned from the method call , you can just iterate over it like this .

```
List<Position> allPos = posDBM.getAllPos();
for(Position position : allPos){
   //Your code goes here
 }
```

And if you want to initialize a new list you can do it in many ways by using different implementations of List interface , now which implementation you want to choose very much depends on your requirement.

Comment: It was just a question out of interest, I was not meant for practical usage

Comment: No problem , keep the interest up :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to add a breakpoint and see allPos variable after posDBM.getAllPos(), the debugger should tell you the Type.